# Want to source the login IDs after "@"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to source the login IDs in the column "I" under column header "description"
.
All the login IDs start with "@" and have no space in between.

I want to source only the login IDs from the said column.

Please find the attached SS for reference.
Any codes or formula to do the job?

Yours,
SDG

[image]

Comment: There is no (sample)data included, plus your own attempt is missing. Please check [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question.

Comment: well you can use left(), len(), find() and right() to good effect, I use it to do similar tasks often ie separating names and numbers. But with no data to work with...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using the functions I suggested in the comment:

[image]

Had a go with MID() as well. But only tested on one example, not typing in more.

Comment: I have found some sample data in OP's post and edited the question if you want to revise your answer. I think it's already quite nice you do answer it :)

Comment: Yes, agreed some are nice little 'puzzles'. Have you tried `=MID(A6,5,FIND("</",A6)-5)` though? ID's seem to start at 5th character, 4th if OP needs to include `@`.

Comment: Perfect reasoning :)